# I want to find the text between most inner {}

Tags: javascript, regex

## Research:

I don't know how to even go in this direction. Searched google. `\{[^{}]*\}` got the regex, but this matches only up to 2 levels.

## So, my question is

```
{
  {
    {
     I need regex/javascript to match this text.
    }
  }
}
```

The number of `{}` may vary. But i want only the text which is between the most inner `{}`

My actual test case.:

```
for(i=0;i<=50;i++){for(j=0;j<50;j++){$('body').append('hey I am a bug<br>');}}
```

I need to match `$('body').append('hey I am a bug<br>');`. But as I said, there can be any number of nested loops. I'm asking this to help another user on SO

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick parser for the task.

```
var text = "{ {t} { { text! } } }";
var best = 0, height = 0;
var curText = '';
var winner = '';
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == '{') {
        height++;
        curText = '';
    } else if (text[i] == '}') {
        if (height > best) {
            winner = curText;
            best = height;
        }
        curText = '';
        height--;
    } else {
        curText += text[i];
    }
}
// Answer is in the variable "winner".
```

Comment: Would return only `a` for `{{a}{b}}`

Comment: @jantimon: Correct. It's not hard to modify the program to keep b instead or both a and b.

Answer (score 2):

What about searching for all characters except `{` and `}`?
 `/\{([^\{\}]+)\}/`

[image: Regexp]

```
"{ {} { { text! } } }".match(/\{([^\{\}]+)\}/g)[1] // Returns text !
```